# Docker & Amazon Beanstalk - Deploy an Angular application

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am trying to deploy a dist folder that is generated with versioning by Gulp using a Dockerfile and with Amazon EB.

This fails when I run eb deploy with:

> COPY dist /var/www/html dist: no such file or directory. Check snapshot logs for details. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Is this because the dist directory is not under source control? If so, what is the best way to transfer the dist directory up to EB whilst still using my docker file to deploy and configure the application?

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nimmis/apache-php5

COPY dist /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: The best way is to deploy static assets directly to S3 or better, cloudfront, rather than having your EB service them

Comment: I was mistaken by it being a static site as I needed to run PHP in order to generate a share page for my site. I instead opted for deploying an artifact through Beanstalk. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my understanding of eb deploy was the issue. Answer is to zip the dist directory, along with other files using a bash script and create my own artifact for the config.yml file:

e.g.

dist (application files)
config (php.ini and 000-default.conf)
Dockerfile

Then add the directory to the config.yml:

```
deploy:
artifact: dist.zip
```

I was then able to write a bash script to create a version number label and then deploy to Beanstalk:

eb deploy --staged --label {version_number}

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the dist files in your docker image then install gulp and run the command to generate the dist folder within the Dockerfile.

See the RUN command for Dockerfiles

Comment: That is another option although I wanted a cleaner deployment directory. I instead went for deploying an artifact through Beanstalk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I want to ask why do we need to build that within the docker, I mean it wouldnt be faster to build the docker image if we just add the folder, and maybe add a npm install? 
I guess is due some perms os something like that, can you advice me on why is the the best practice ?